# Fitering rows of one CSV file based on two values from another file in Bash

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have two CSV files.

- One is long with columns: `Chr_Name`, `h`, `j`, `start_pos`, `end_pos`.
- Another is short file including columns `Chr_Name` and `position`.

I need to filter the rows from the first file based on `Chr_Name` first and then the position that falls between the start and end position of the first file.

How can I do that?

Example:

- File 1:

  ```
  Chrk, 10, 20,  1010, 1025
  Chrk, 20, 10, 1020, 1040
  ChrM, 10, 10, 50, 120
  ```
- File 2:

  ```
  Chrk, 1030
  ChrM, 70
  ```
- Desired output file:

  ```
  Chrk, 20, 10, 1020, 1040
  ChrM, 10, 10, 50, 120
  ```

Comment: Also, why bash and awk? Neither seems to be an appropriate tool here. Simply loading the two CSV files into an in-memory or temporary database using `sqlite3` would make this significantly easier, and if your data is large, faster

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) results generated by your code

Comment: Your CSV file has whitespace between columns?

Comment: @MarcusMüller maybe some people find using a DB easier, but I cannot imagine how the complication of actually loading into a DB could possibly be easier than a simple awk script! If you think it is, please post an answer explaining the approach, I would be interested. But presumably it requires at least two steps (create the DB, then run the relevant query) so I really don't see how it could be considered simpler.

Comment: Do you _really_ have comma-separated fields? Is neither file actually a standard bed file?

Comment: @terdon Kusalananda already did :)

Comment: Ah, yes, well, that seems very far from simple to me. I thought you might have a simpler approach.

Comment: @terdon I guess you're right in that simplicity depends on the reader; I got the feedback from a CSV-juggling user that they were very happy that they could use SQL to manage their data instead of trying to learn new tools. This will not make it easier to *you*, but for future readers: I broke down a simpler sqlite-based workflow in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/742021/split-a-csv-file-based-on-second-column-value/742027#742027

Comment: @MarcusMüller while I agree that for more complicated CSVs some other tool might be appropriate, doing what the OP wants with the format of CSVs they posted is trivial in awk and as a bonus an awk solution is portable to all POSIX systems since awk is a mandatory POSIX tool so I think that **in this case** using awk is a very reasonable approach.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have two CSV files as follows:

```bash
$ cat file1
Chr_Name,h,j,start_pos,end_pos
Chrk,10,20,1010,1025
Chrk,20,10,1020,1040
ChrM,10,10,50,120
```

```bash
$ cat file2
Chr_Name,position
Chrk,1030
ChrM,70
```

You may use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to [*join*](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs/#join) the two files on the common field `Chr_Name`, [*filter*](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs/#filter) the resulting data by extracting only the records that have a `position` field that fall between `start_pos` and `end_pos`, and then finally [*cut*](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs/#cut) the unwanted `position` field from the data.

```bash
$ mlr --csv join -f file2 -j Chr_Name then filter '$start_pos <= $position && $position <= $end_pos' then cut -x -f position file1
Chr_Name,h,j,start_pos,end_pos
Chrk,20,10,1020,1040
ChrM,10,10,50,120
```

The `mlr` command, nicely formatted:

```bash
mlr --csv \
    join -f file2 -j Chr_Name then \
    filter '$start_pos <= $position && $position <= $end_pos' then \
    cut -x -f position \
    file1
```

---

With the same two files as above, but using SQLite3 with an in-memory database [as suggested by Marcus Müller in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/757502/fitering-rows-of-one-csv-file-based-on-two-values-from-another-file-in-bash#comment1443170_757502):

```bash
$ sqlite3 :memory: '.mode csv' '.headers on' '.import file1 file1' '.import file2 file2' 'SELECT file1.* FROM file1 JOIN file2 ON (file1.Chr_Name = file2.Chr_name) WHERE CAST(position AS INTEGER) BETWEEN start_pos AND end_pos'
Chr_Name,h,j,start_pos,end_pos
Chrk,20,10,1020,1040
ChrM,10,10,50,120
```

The SQLite3 statements:

```sql
.mode csv
.headers on
.import file1 file1
.import file2 file2

SELECT file1.* FROM file1
    JOIN file2 ON (file1.Chr_Name = file2.Chr_name)
    WHERE CAST(position AS INTEGER) BETWEEN start_pos AND end_pos
```

The dotted commands imports the two files into the tables `file1` and `file2` while the `SELECT` statement performs the actual query.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk, regardless of whether you really do have spaces after the `,`s or not:

```
$ awk -F', *' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} ($1 in a) && ($4 <= a[$1]) && (a[$1] <= $5)' File2 File1
Chrk, 20, 10, 1020, 1040
ChrM, 10, 10, 50, 120
```